Static friction, no work
Imagine a ball rolling without slipping on the floor. Then the force of static friction has non-zero torque, so why it doesn't change the overall energy of the ball?

If the ball is undergoing pure  rolling on a horizontal surface with no external applied  horizontal forces acting on it, then there there will be no static friction force acting on it.


Imagine a ball rolling without slipping on the floor. Then the force
of static friction has non-zero torque, so why it doesn't change the
overall energy of the ball?

It does change the energy of the ball.
If there is friction causing non-zero torque, then there is a change in the angular velocity of the ball and since this is a no slip condition, the linear velocity is also reducing and along with it, the linear kinetic energy is also reducing. Since there is a force acting, after travelling a finite distance there must be negative work done.
I prefer to call it rolling resistance which is slightly different to static friction and usually has a lower value. Static friction becomes more significant when for example accelerating a car, but when free rolling with negligible acceleration, the static friction is also negligible. When a horizontal force is applied to a block, the static resistance is proportional to the applied force until the limit is reached and the block starts sliding. Rolling resistance is different because it is constant and independent of the velocity.

Thanks, but what if we ignore rolling resistance? Because as far as I
know, there is static friction force and that's why the ball is
rolling and not slipping. – Piotr H

If a ball is rolling without slipping on a rough surface and then encounters a smooth patch that is completely frictionless, the ball will continue rolling without slipping due to conservation of linear and angular momentum. No friction is required to sustain rolling motion. If the ball is speeding up or slowing down, then there is a certain amount static friction involved to prevent slipping.

Thanks, but what if we ignore rolling resistance? Because as far as I know, there is static friction force and that's why the ball is rolling and not slipping.

Extended my answer.

Thanks a lot. :)

You are very welcome :-)
